# Will testflight add new UDID to my Apple developer account automatically

Tags: iphone, testflight

We want to do a private beta testing of our iPhone app using testflight very soon.  One thing we are not very clear is how to add new users automatically to a published build.  My understanding is when a user accepts a testflight invite and follows through testflight instructions to submit his UDID, we still need to add the UDID to the ad hoc distribution profile and rebuild the application in Xcode with the updated profile, and then upload a new build to testflight.  Lately I heard from someone Testflight can automatically add the new UDID to our provisional profile and there is no need for new build for the new user to be able to install the application.  I found this hard to believe, but I want to check with the community whether there is an easier way to add new user to an existing build.  Many thanks.

Answer (score 2):

If that's possible I'd be the first wanting to know. AFAIK, you have to manually upload the device list (although you can get this file from test flight, which simplifies, albeit not tremendously, the nightmarish process of updating your profiles).

Can't imagine how Testflight would even be able to do the update short of asking your Apple Developer credentials, which it doesn't.

You can however upload an updated mobile provisioning file to Testflight and it will automatically update the already uploaded apps so that the added UDIDs are allowed. At least saves you the pain of having to rebuild the app.